# 408 request timeout if web app is idle for about one minute

Tags: php, post, timeout

I have a web app written in php, javascript and html.  The app has some buttons, which when pressed use ajax to get data from a godaddy shared server, where my website is hosted.  I've recently learned that if the web page is left idle for about one minute, pressing these buttons results in 408 Request Timeouts.  The method that I'm doing is a POST.

I don't know where to begin to fix this.  My guess is that I should be able to adjust this timeout period, but I'm not sure.  Is a timeout of one minute normal?  Is my app (i.e. client) supposed to deal with this better? Any help is appreciated.

I should also add that if I do the POST again (immediately following the 408 Request Timeout) it's successful.

**EDIT: Removed header because I didn't want my website name showing.

So far I've observed the issue on Safari and Android.  Firefox doesn't appear to have the problem.  I've not tested any other browsers.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

This should only happen if a request is open for quite some time. Are you opening a HTTP connection without sending anything through?

If your http request is short and quickly handled, and you're still getting the 408 I would recommend talking to godaddy support.

Comment: I'll look into this first thing tomorrow, but I don't think I'm opening an HTTP connection without sending anything through.

Comment: I added a debug to the php script that handles the POST, which writes one word to a file on the server.  This is the first thing that the script does (it's actually right after the call to session_start() ).   When this problem happens the word does not get printed to the file.  This may have been obvious to some, but I wanted to rule out a php/MySql problem.

Comment: I've now found that this does not happen in firefox.  It does happen in Safari.  I've contacted godaddy and the person on the phone reported the issue to the tech department.  Any ideas given that it happens with Safari and not Firefox?

Comment: No, I really have no idea. I would start debugging by inspecting the network traffic. It's quite hard to give you real answers without having access to your code.

Comment: I've just replicated this 408 on my Android phone, and this is VERY bad because my web site is mostly used by mobile users.

Comment: Ok, I see the error. You must contact godaddy for this. I found a number of forum postings related : http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/your-request-timed-out-please-retry-the-request-4/

Comment: Thanks Evert.  I contacted godaddy yesterday, so hopefully something will come of that.  I will check that link you posted.  Cheers.

Comment: By the way, I compared the headers of Firefox and Safari when the POSTS are successful.  The only difference that I noticed was that Firefox shows "Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK" with the POST.  Safari only shows "Status Code: 200 OK".  I don't know if this is significant.

Comment: nothing shows up in the server error logs.  I've been in contact with godaddy's support and so far I've gotten no where.  As an experiment I switched from a POST to a GET and I've not seen the issue with the GET.  I don't foresee an issue with using the GET method in my ajax so perhaps this is a good work around?

Comment: I'd say the best thing you could possibly do, is go to a different host. You can get cheaper and hosts that will care more about your problems; plus godaddy loved things like SOPA, and their owner has done some very unethical things. Switch to something decent.